# Getting all of combinations of features found on two layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlay, union

This is a problem that seems like it should be simple, but it's a little difficult to explain. I have two polygon layers, each with a few hundred features (specifically the districts of England and the constituencies of England). What I want is to produce a third polygon layer, which would take in all of the combinations of districts and constituencies.

See the example below for a much simpler version, the first layer has features 1 and 2, the second layer has features 3 and 4. In this case you would want to get four features out -the intersection of 1 from the first layer and 3 from the second, 1 from the first and 4 from the second, 2 from the first and 3 from the second, 2 from the first and 4 from the second.

Is this possible, and is there a more elegant way of phrasing this that I'm not seeing?

[image: Illustration of the problem - I want a third layer with the features being the combinations of all the features in the first two.]

Comment: Two layers are overlapped, right?

Comment: Yes, they cover the same geography and are in the same CRS.

Comment: What if feature1 doesn't overlap by any feature in layer2? it remains `1`?

Comment: Ideally I'd set things up to avoid that happening but I would want the feature in the new layer to have attributes 1, NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Intersection` tool in "Processing Toolbox <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> > Vector overlay" for this.

For example, I have two layers as below:

[image]

After using `Intersection` tool, you get a new layer:

[image]

And using "Field Calculator" you can make a new field. Expression: `id1 + ',' + id2`

[image]

Result:

[image]